# Is it possible to convert an IO type to Arbitrary?

Tags: haskell, io

I am building a Sudoku solver in Haskell, and I have two functions:

```
genProblemm :: Node -> IO Node
newSudoku   :: IO Node
```

for generating Sudoku puzzles.  I would like to use the `QuickCheck` library to test my solver. Is it possible to make `Node` an instance of [`Arbitrary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#t:Arbitrary), using these functions?  I couldn't find a general way...

I only got as far as the type:

```
instance Arbitrary Node where
  arbitrary =
```

... but I don't know how to write `arbitrary` using my existing functions, which both are `IO` types.

edits:

```
Node = (Sudoku, [(Column, Row, [Int])])
type Sudoku = (Row,Column) -> Int
```

A Node is the whole Sudoku.

Comment: What is `Arbitrary`?

Comment: Are we talking `QuickCheck`?

Comment: Also, what is a `Node`?  Is it a single cell in a puzzle?  Is it a whole puzzle?

Comment: `arbitraty` Your lack of precision disturbs me.

Comment: Thank you, maybe i was a little too quick..

Comment: Unless your algorithm genuinely does IO, which I might suspect it doesn't -- it just uses random numbers, right? -- there is no need to keep it there. The moment you bring it out of IO, QuickCheck has instances for most basic types and random libraries.

Comment: The hardest part will be making the `Arbitrary Sudoku` instance depending upon what `Value` is. The second hardest part will be "cutting the generation down": it'll be easy to make complete arbitrary such things, but difficult to productively create ones which are *valid*.

Comment: There is actually a straightforward answer to this question once we get past wording and the "What is `Arbitrary`" problem. The answer is "No." The asker wants to implement `arbitrary` using a function of type `IO Node` or `Node -> IO Node`, which is impossible because `arbitrary` must be of type `Gen a`, and `Gen` doesn't expose `IO`. The correct follow-up question is: why is `newSudoku` in `IO`? Can you rewrite it using the functions available in `Test.QuickCheck.Gen`?